# PHP - Compare 2 different multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this `$firstarray` :

```
Array
(
    [1] => page->Accueil  // <--- This $key
    [2] => contact->Contact
    [3] => page->Page Test
    [4] => gallery->Test
    [6] => article->test
)
```

And here's the `$secondarray` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => page 
            [1] => 1  //<--- With this $value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => contact
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => page
            [1] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => gallery
            [1] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => article
            [1] => 6
        )

)
```

I need to compare if the `$key` of the `$firstarray` equals to `$value[]` of the `$secondarray`, here's what I tried so far and didn't work :

```
foreach ($firstarray as $key => $value) {
if (array_key_exists($key, $secondarray)) {
echo "Ok";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
foreach ($firstarray as $key => $value) 
{
   foreach ($secondary as $key2 => $value2) 
   {
        if(in_array($key, $value2)
        {
            echo "Ok"; 
            break;  
        } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
foreach ($secondarray as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($value[1], $firstarray)) {
        echo "Ok";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$testArray = array("page"=>"Accueil",
    "contact"=>"Contact",
    "page"=>"Page Test",
    "gallery"=>"Test",
    "article"=>"test");

$testArray2 = array(array('page' => '1'),array( 'contact'=> '2'));
foreach ($testArray as $key => $value) {
    for($i =0; $i < sizeof($testArray2); $i++){
        if(array_key_exists($key, $testArray2[$i])){
            echo "ok"
        }
    }


}
```